# Safari & Firefox will not Ajax until server has closed connection - node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http, cross-browser

Using node.js I am sending HTML to a page.

However, it seems that when a script arrives at the client that sends an AJAX request it will not initiate until the DOM has completed being sent (closing body and html tags).

Chrome fires the request as soon as the script tag has been sent which I see as correct behaviour ... am I doing something wrong? If not is there a way round it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open('POST', '/request', true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhttp.send('fname=Henry&lname=Ford');
    </script>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not sending it until the document is entirely loaded?

Comment: @kizeloo Because I leave the connection open and it will wait until the connection is closed...